# C# program to execute sudo and ftp commands on remote linux machine

Tags: c#

I would like to write a C# program that connects to a linux machine and executes a remote command - 
"sudo -u  ftp ". I have been successful in establishing a ssh connection the the linux machine and execute commands like ps -ef or ls but am not able to sudo and ftp to another server

Comment: Could someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is your exact problem/error? Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to learn how to ask proper questions. Have fun!